# In Fig. $9.16$, $P$ is a point in the interior of a parallelogram $ABCD$.

Tags: geometry

[image]

In Fig. $9.16$, $P$ is a point in the interior of a parallelogram $ABCD$.
Show that $ar[APB]+ar[PCD]=1/2 \cdot ar[ABCD]$

I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Draw $h$ which passes through $P$

[image]

Note that $h=x+y$, then $$A(\triangle APB)+A(\triangle DPC)=\frac{\overline{AB}\cdot x}{2}+\frac{\overline{DC}\cdot y}{2}$$
How $ABCD$ is a paralellogram then $\overline{AB}=\overline{DC}$

$$\frac{\overline{AB}\cdot x}{2}+\frac{\overline{DC}\cdot y}{2}=\frac{\overline{DC}\cdot x}{2}+\frac{\overline{DC}\cdot y}{2}=\frac{\overline{DC}(x+y)}{2}=\frac{\overline{DC}\cdot h}{2}=\frac{A(ABCD)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(APB)$ be the area of the figure $APB$.

Draw a line parallel to $AB$ which passes through the point $P$. And let $E,F$ be the intersection point of the line and $BC,AD$ respectively.

Then, noting that the figures $ABEF, FECD$ are parallelograms, we have
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{(APB)}+\color{green}{(PCD)}&=\color{red}{(AEB)}+\color{green}{(ECD)}\\&=\color{red}{\frac 12(ABEF)}+\color{green}{\frac 12(FECD)}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left((ABEF)+(FECD)\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}(ABCD).\end{align}$$